# Plot becomes distorted when uploading to latex using epslatex in gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot, overleaf

I wrote the code for a plot in gnuplot and set the output using epslatex terminal as follows:

```
set term epslatex color
set output "test.tex"

set multiplot layout 2,3 columnsfirst margins 0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9 spacing 0.07,0.0

unset key

set format x " "
#set xtic 400
#set ytic 100
#unset xlabel

set yrange [0:150]

set title "D1"


plot [0:10] x**2 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7

#unset key
unset format x

unset title


plot [0:10] x**2 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7



set format x " "


set title "D2"


plot [0:10] x**2 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7

unset format x


unset title
 
 
plot [0:10] x**2 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7



set format x " "


set title "D3"


plot [0:10] x**2 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7

unset format x
unset title

set label 1 "$x $"  at screen 0.47,0.04 
set label 2 "$f(x)$"  at screen 0.05,0.43 rotate by 90 
set label 3 "$ (a)\\; NK $" at -25.2696,239.562
set label 4 "$ (b) \\; NKH \\Delta $" at -25.4174,102,370

set key at -22.5856,276.937 box

plot [0:10] x**2 title "$ x^2 $" lc -1 lw 2 with lines , [0:5] x**3 title "$ x^3 $" lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.7

unset label 1
unset label 2
unset label 3
unset label 4

unset multiplot

set output
```

When setting output using `set terminal jpeg size 1800,900` , I am getting the following:
[image: plot1]

But after setting the output using epslatex , I am getting a distorted image as follows:
[image: plot2]

How do I reconcile the outputs and make the later look like the former?

The resulting ".tex" file from the gnuplot code is as follows:

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(588,2520){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(588,3863){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(720,2300){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} }}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(1511,4865){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}D1}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(588,504){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(588,1847){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(720,284){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(2676,2520){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(2676,3863){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(2808,2300){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} }}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(3599,4865){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}D2}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(2676,504){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(2676,1847){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(2808,284){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(4764,2520){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(4764,3863){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(4896,2300){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} }}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(5687,4865){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}D3}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(4764,504){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(4764,1847){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(4896,284){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(3384,202){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$x $}}%
      \put(360,2167){\rotatebox{90}{\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$f(x)$}}}%
      \put(896,3722){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$ (a)\; NK $}}%
      \put(872,1874){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$ (b) \; NKH \Delta $}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(466,4114){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$ x^2 $}}%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(466,3894){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$ x^3 $}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{test}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

And the latex code used to plot it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{plot}
\author{anon }
\date{February 2022}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{test.tex}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The ".eps" file is available here :
[test.eps](https://filedropper.com/d/s/7BiKlprzReAmhookWBqBa9SoPBgNea)

Comment: Can you share both the resulting files from your script as well as a [mre] of your latex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have included those now.

Comment: Can you also share the image `test`?

Comment: you mean the .eps file that I get? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: yes, please. Github, dropbox, etc might be helpful to share it

Comment: @D.K. with the jpeg terminal you explicitely set `set terminal jpeg size 1800,900`. I would assume if you don't explicitly set the terminal size of the epslatex terminal, the default size will be taken which probably has a different aspect ratio, hence leading to a "distorted" image. Just a thought.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited that in too

Comment: @theozh I tried to set the same size in epslatex terminal but while compiling in overleaf the picture doesn't show and an error occurs "Float too large for page".

Comment: @D.K. Then make the size smaller, but with the same aspect ratio

Comment: unfortunately the picture environment does  not allow to set the unit lengths separately, like tikz does. The closest one can get to fixing this from the latex site is probably `\scalebox{1}[0.75]{\input{test.tex}}`, but the font is terrible distorted...

Comment: @D.K. to what exactly have you set the epslatex terminal size? `set term epslatex color size 1800,900`? Default units are inches. So, this will be interpreted as 1800 inches x 900 inches, maybe a bit large. Maybe try e.g. `set term epslatex color size 18cm,9cm`.

Comment: @theozh I tried the size 21 cm, 9 cm and I am getting output as follows: [link](https://filedropper.com/d/s/J4MM5cptwuxzbYqaQWtj3JVRhaNaSz) . The image seems to go out of bounds in the right side. How do I shift it more towards the left?

Comment: @D.K. The default textwidth in your document is about 12cm. Make it smaller!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz changing the font size in gnuplot code does not seem to have the desired effect with setting the output in latex. The words seem to change position.

Answer (score 0):

[original was answer based on a guess shown to be incorrect by the uploaded sample code]

To get a more complete answer I think you need to show the LaTeX code at the site of inclusion.

**Amended answer**

As theozh points out, you need to use a consistent aspect ratio. If I modify your original script to use

```
set term epslatex color size 6in, 3in
```

and modify the top of your .tex script to say

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

leaving all else the same as you show, I get the figure below. You have used a mixture of screen coordinates and plot coordinates to position the text labels.  I'm not sure which of those is better, but mixing them may not be a good idea.

[image]

Comment: I have included that now in the question.

Comment: Can these abel adjustments be done directly from the latex code without changing the gnuplot code? Also, can the key box dimension be changed from the latex code itself?